# Box Api GET Folder Items With Offset and Limit Not Working

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, box

I am attempting to retrieve the list of items within a folder in the Box.com api (and use the offset/limit for paging).

According to [the docs](https://developer.box.com/v2.0/reference#get-a-folders-items), I should do this:

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/FOLDER_ID/items?limit=2&offset=0 \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Which seems very simple. And I believe I am following these instructions to the letter, as shown by my code below:

```
        var boxUrl = "https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/" + folderId + "/items";
        var requestParams = new NameValueCollection();
        requestParams.Add("limit", "10");
        requestParams.Add("offset", "50");
        var array = (from key in requestParams.AllKeys
                     from value in requestParams.GetValues(key)
                     select string.Format("{0}={1}", key, value))
            .ToArray();
        var queryString = string.Join("&", array);
        var url = boxUrl + "?" + queryString;
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(boxEmailUrl);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

When I debug this code, the value `url` is:

```
https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/347534773457/items?limit=10&offset=50
```

And that seems absolutely correct. But the response I get back gives me the first 100 records, instead of records 50-60. In fact, the meta data I get back from this api call shows `"offset":0, "limit":100`, as if I didn't provide any `limit` or `offset` params at all. Here is a small snippet of that:

```
{"total_count":101,"entries":[
{"type":"folder","id":"493... 
...917","sequence_id":"0","etag":"0","name":"xxxxxxx"}],
"offset":0,"limit":100,"order": [{"by":"type", "direction":"ASC"},{"by":"name","direction":"ASC"}]}
```

Could this be a bug in Box.com's api? Or am I doing something wrong in my api call?